# Unable to put a string value into python using Chaquopy from Kotlin

Tags: python, android-studio, kotlin, chaquopy

I am currently doing my final year project which uses Python as the backend for a module. I found that Chaquopy is a possible library.

Everything runs fine until I try to pass a string value from my Kotlin code into the Python script. It just keeps not taking the string value as an argument for my Python function and print nothing back into the text file where the output is supposed to be printed.

Can anyone help me with a fix? Thanks. *Sorry for the bad coding as I am not very familiar with Python and the Chaquopy library

**A Quick Edit:** The string value is named as movie which was passed in from the previous fragment

The code for calling the Python script from Kotlin is as below:

```
if (! Python.isStarted()) {
            Python.start(AndroidPlatform(requireContext()))
}

val py = Python.getInstance()    
val pyobj = py.getModule("testScript")
pyobj.callAttr("main", movie)
```

The function in Python:

```
def main(movie):  
    file_dir = str(Python.getPlatform().getApplication().getFilesDir())    
    filename = join(dirname(file_dir),'file.txt')    
    original_stdout = sys.stdout    
    sys.stdout = open(filename, 'w', encoding = 'utf8', errors="ignore")
    print(""+movie)        
    sys.stdout.close()    
    sys.stdout = original_stdout    
    output = open(filename, 'r').read()    
    return str(output)
```

Comment: How do you know nothing is in the text file? Are you downloading it from the device using Android Studio, or are you checking the return value of `callAttr`?

Comment: Are you sure that `movie` isn't an empty string? Try printing it from your Python function before reassigning `sys.stdout`, and you should see the output in the [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) with the tag `python.stdout`.

Comment: Hi, as I am using an emulator so I access the device manager directly from Android Studio for the text file.

Comment: For the movie string, I actually haven't seen it yet as this is done by my teammate and I was not sure about it. I will try it tomorrow and update here about any problem as it is almost 11 PM in Malaysia. Thanks for the help anyway and appreciate it very much.

Comment: Hi again, it turns out that it was my teammate that made a mistake on the previous fragment. There was a typo in the pairing key for the bundle for the movie value. Sorry for causing any trouble and thanks for the help.